# Exporting table to XYZ ASCII file via ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, export, cursor, ascii

I'm looking for a way to export an ArcGIS table (created with the **[Sample tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002v000000)**) to a text file via ArcPy.

I can do this in ArcGIS via the context menu by right-clicking the table, but have not found a way to script this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this using a cursor to grab the data from your table and write to a comma-delimited text file.

EDIT: I'm adding a more concise block of code to accomplish the task using the `csv` module of Python

**New Answer using arcpy.da cursor:**

```
import arcpy,csv

table =r'c:\path\to\table'
outfile = r'c:\path\to\output\ascii\text\file'

#--first lets make a list of all of the fields in the table
fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fields]

with open(outfile,'wb') as f:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,field_names)
    #--write all field names to the output file
    dw.writeheader()

    #--now we make the search cursor that will iterate through the rows of the table
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field_names) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            dw.writerow(dict(zip(field_names,row)))
```

**New Answer using old-style cursor:**

```
import arcpy,csv

table =r'c:\path\to\table'
outfile = r'c:\path\to\output\ascii\text\file'      

#--first lets make a list of all of the fields in the table
fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fields]

with open(outfile,'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    #--write all field names to the output file
    w.writerow(field_names)

    #--now we make the search cursor that will iterate through the rows of the table
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table):
        field_vals = [row.getValue(field.name) for field in fields]
        w.writerow(field_vals)
    del row
```

**Old answer:**

```
import arcpy

table =r'c:\path\to\table'
outfile = r'c:\path\to\output\ascii\text\file'


#--first lets make a list of all of the fields in the table
fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)

i = 1
f = open(outfile,'w')
for field in fields:
    #--write all field names to the output file
    if i < len(fields):
        f.write('%s,' % field.name)
        i += 1
    else:
        f.write('%s\n' % field.name)

#--now we make the search cursor that will iterate through the rows of the table
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
for row in rows:
    i = 1
    for field in fields:
        if i < len(fields):
            f.write('%s,' % row.getValue(field.name))
            i += 1
        else:
            f.write('%s\n' % row.getValue(field.name))
del rows
f.close()
```

Comment: Glad I could help you @Toni

Comment: @Jason - Thanks, this was very helpful. I'm new so I don't have the reputation to comment on your accepted answer. I think there's a small mistake in the new answer that uses an arcpy.da cursor. `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table) as cursor:` should be `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, field_names) as cursor:`

Comment: Good catch @TylerG, I've edited the answer to include the list of fields required by the Data Access cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You may want the "Export Feature Attribute to ASCII", cleverly named arcpy.ExportXYv_stats

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003v000000

```
import arcpy

feature = "path to feature here"
# fieldnames must be explicitly provided. Note that you will get additional fields based on the feature type (e.g., "XCoord" and "YCoord" for point features)
fieldnames = [X.name for X in arcpy.ListFields(feature)]
# delimiter options "SPACE", "COMMA", or "SEMI-COLON"
# header options "ADD_FIELD_NAMES" or "NO_FIELD_NAMES"
arcpy.ExportXYv_stats(feature, fieldnames, "SPACE", "path to outfile", "ADD_FIELD_NAMES")
```

Comment: +1 for sleuthing! This works interactively but not as well in  a model or script, because the field names must be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code I use. It helps me generates all my output files to .txt file with a range from 0,100. Hopefully it helps

```
for x in xrange(0,100):
    if os.path.isfile(outfolder + "/" + "outputs" + str(x) +".shp" ):
       inFeatures = "selected_features" + str(x) +".shp"
       export_ASCII = "ASCII " + str(x) +".txt"
       arcpy.ExportXYv_stats(inFeatures, ["Cur1_pr2","Cur3_pl1","slp1"],"SPACE", export_ASCII,"ADD_FIELD_NAMES")
```