# Export attribute table (feature class) to text file in batch?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, export, file-geodatabase, feature-class

What would be the most efficient way to export attribute tables from multiple feature class files stored in a file geodatabase? Export to .txt or .csv. Is there any sort of batch process? Or python script?

I have hundreds of files within this geodatabase and really need to automate this process.

Comment: Take a look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42445/8104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Python, you can use [arcpy.ListDatasets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001m000000) to create an object to loop through all the features in your file geodatabase, setting the workspace to the geodatabase first. Then, for each feature use [arcpy.MakeTableView_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006v000000) to create a table view that can then be used by [arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000) to export the tables to Excel. All of these documentation pages should provide you with enough code snippets to get you there.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across `CopyRows_management()` to convert shapefile attribute tables to csv. For example:

```
import arcpy
my_shp = 'lat_lon.shp'
out_csv = 'points.csv'

arcpy.CopyRows_management(my_shp, out_csv)
```

Comment: Please, could you elaborate this answer? It could help other users in the future.

Comment: A good answer should include not only what to use, but also how to use it.  Please [edit] your answer to expand on how to use the `copyrows_management()`.