# Arcpy TabletoExcel input error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export, excel, error-000814

I have a very big dataset in a gbd. I would like to export it to an excel file. I use the following code:

```
startingP = r"C:\Directory\ArcGIS\By_Coding.gdb\MyInput"
endingP = r"C:\Directory\ArcGIS\By_Coding.gdb\Output.xls"
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion (startingP,endingP)
```

But what I get is:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000814: Invalid file type
```

I have already seen [in another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92359/export-attribute-table-feature-class-to-text-file-in-batch) that it was suggested to combine `arcpy.TabletoExcel_conversion` with other tools like `ListDataset`and with `MakeTableView_management`but it sounds weird to me that there is no faster way to do it, because I always thought the arcpy functions perfectly replicated the corresponding Arcgis toolbox tools, and if I use `Arctoolbox > Conversion Tools > Excel > Excel to Table` using the input file "MyInput" as "Input Table", it works. Is therefore any mistake in the way I call my variables in the code?

Comment: save it to your desktop or somewhere else besides the GDB and it should work

Comment: Thank you that was indeed the problem, but why python does not like the gdb as output directory?

Comment: when you used the tool from arctoolbox were you able to save the .xls into your GDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're trying to save your output in your geodatabase. 
Change `endingP` to:

```
endingP = r"C:\Directory\ArcGIS\output.xls"
```

And see if that works.

Comment: It was! Thank you a lot! I was so sure the problem was in my input file and not in the output directory, but I was focusing on the wrong problem. But why does it not accept the geodatabase as a valid output directory?

Comment: I know that some python functions don't work well with Arc's geodatabases, they're unable to read them, so I suspect it's something similar going on here too. For example: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm